# Copying entire folder structure from a role merging/overwriting with already existing files

Tags: ansible

I use Ansible to deploy my userspecific configuration (shell, texteditor, etc.) on a newly installed system. That's why i have all config files in my roles file directory, structured the same way as they should be placed in my home directory.

What's the correct way to realize this? I don't want to list every single file in the role and exisiting files should be overwriten, existing directories should be merged.

I've tried the copy module, but the whole task is skipped; I assume because the parent directory(.config) already exist.

Edit: add the requested additional information

Ansible Version: 2.9.9

The roles copy task:

```
- name: Install user configurations
  copy:
    src: "home/"
    dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}"
```

The Files to copy in the role directory:

```
desktop-enviroment
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
├── files
│   └── home
│       ├── .config
│       │   ├── autostart-scripts
│       │   │   └── ssh-keys.sh
│       │   ├── MusicBrainz
│       │   │   ├── Picard
│       │   │   ├── Picard.conf
│       │   │   └── Picard.ini
│       │   ├── sublime-text-3
│       │   │   ├── Installed Packages
│       │   │   ├── Lib
│       │   │   ├── Local
│       │   │   └── Packages
│       │   └── yakuakerc
│       └── .local
│           └── share
│               ├── plasma
│               └── yakuake
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── meta
│   └── main.yml
├── tasks
│   ├── desktop-common.yaml
│   ├── desktop-gnome.yaml
│   ├── desktop-kde.yaml
│   └── main.yml
├── templates
└── vars
    └── main.yml
```

The relevant ansible output:

```
TASK [desktop-enviroment : Install user configurations] **
ok: [localhost]
```

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, the copy module sounds like the way to go. Can you show us your `copy:` yaml code and the output when you try to run it?

Comment: Hello, Read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ans paste your copy module and your ansible version

Comment: Did you try the synchronise module ? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html

Comment: @papey is this the same module as this https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/synchronize_module.html#status ?
I will try it later this day.

Comment: It seems the problem was totally my fault, i overlooked/forget that this role was run with become: yes. So all the files were copied to roots home.